# Unity: GetComponent<BaseClass<T>> - are there any workarounds for this?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If an object has a component with a baseclass `BaseClass<T>`, calling `GetComponent<BaseClass<T>>()` will not return that component.  The generic argument seems to throw it off, as a `BaseClass` without using generics will correctly return the derived class as a component when `GetComponent<BaseClass>()` is called.

Does anyone know a solid workaround for this?  The use of a generic arg in this class is somewhat important, so I'd obviously rather not re-write the program's class structure just to accommodate this.

Here's a rough sketch of the classes in question

```
//the base class that I'd like to be able to fetch the subclasses of using GetComponent
public abstract class BaseUIClass<T> : MonoBehaviour where T :BaseEntity {}

//EntityType1&2 are derived from BaseEntity
public class DerivedUIClass1 : BaseUIClass<EntityType1> {}
public class DerivedUIClass2 : BaseUIClass<EntityType2> {}
```

BaseUIClass has this method:

```
public virtual void Setup(T entity) {}
```

Which needs to be called shortly after the component is added to a GO.

EDIT:

Effectively what I'm looking to do is the following, without having to hard-code in (I want to actually make use of the generic args I've defined)

```
if(uiClassObj is typeof(DerivedUIClass1) go.GetComponent<BaseUIClass<EntityType1>>();

else if(uiClassObj is typeof(DerivedUIClass2) go.GetComponent<BaseUIClass<EntityType2>>();
//etc
```

But considering that there is a component of type `BaseUIClass<BaseEntity>` on the go, and the two+ derived classes I'm interested in are defined by `DerivedUIClass1<EntityType1>` and `DerivedUIClass2<EntityType2>`, the conversion should surely just be implicit?

Comment: Can you show how `BaseClass` is declared ?

Comment: @Programmer done

Comment: Ok. How about your `BaseEntity`? Just something enough to check if there is a workaround or this or not. Finally, which one are you trying to use `GetComponent` on that is failing or returning null?

Comment: BaseEntity is essentially the logic that the UI view is getting events from, so the BaseEntity class hierarchy is essentially in parallel with BaseUIClass.  DerivedUIClass1 handles the UI for EntityType1, etc.  Importantly, each EntityType can have pretty different logic on top of the shared base class methods.

Comment: I'm calling `GetComponent<BaseUIClass<BaseEntity>>()` which returns null.  Essentially what I'm after is that if the BaseUIClass is DerivedUIClass1, `GetComponent<BaseUIClass<EntityType1>>()`, if it's DerivedUIClass2, `GetComponent<BaseUIClass<EntityType2>>()` etc - but obviously I'd rather not hard-code a switch statement like this

Comment: updated the question to be a bit clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you want the way you want, because Unity doesn't accept components which are generic classes.

I.E., if you have:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> : MonoBehaviour {}
```

you will not be able to add it as a component unless you specify `T` via a subclass inheriting from it:

```
public class MySpecifiedClass : MyGenericClass<[specificType]> {}
```

So, to solve your problem, you should simply implement a specific interface for everything that should be done when the base class is added as a component. I'll show you an example with `float` and `int` derived types, you can extend easily to any type you need.

**BaseClass**

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public interface ISetup {
    void CallSetup();
}

public class BaseClass<T> : MonoBehaviour, ISetup {
    public T myEntity;

    public void CallSetup() {
        Setup(myEntity);
    }

    private void Setup(T entity) {
        Debug.Log(entity);
        //Your setup code
    }
}
```

**Your components classes**

```cs
public class BaseClassInt : BaseClass<int> {
    private void Awake() {
        myEntity = 25;
    }
}
public class BaseClassFloat : BaseClass<float> {
    private void Awake() {
        myEntity = 10.6f;
    }
}
```

**Code that gets the interface and calls Setup()**

```cs
var componentsWithSetup = GetComponents<ISetup>();
foreach (var component in componentsWithSetup) {
    component.CallSetup();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One workaround would be to use a specific type instead of a generic type at the top level for each type that you need the base class for.

For example:

```
public class SpecificToFirstTypeClass : BaseClass<FirstType>
{
}
```

and then use `GetComponent<SpecificToFirstTypeClass>`

Based on a suggestion from [this answers.unity.com question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/36628/components-using-generics.html)

Comment: Yeah spotted that suggestion, looks like I'll go with that for now but was wondering if there was a cleaner way; creating an additional class just to band-aid this functionality isn't ideal, especially if I have lots of generic classes that need to inherit from different specific-type classes

Comment: That is a clean approach IMO.

Comment: It actually doesn't work for my particular use-case though, as the whole point of using generics is not knowing what derived class a particular object has at runtime.  Updated my original code - as you can see, the type of derived component on a gameobject could be either DerivedUIClass1 or DerivedUIClass2, and after getting the component I then need to run Setup(T).

Comment: This all works fine in a stricty C# environment but the GetComponent<>() method is making this extremely tricky it seems..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't believe this didn't work so I hacked it using tags, where UI is a base, abstract class:

```
public UI currentUI;

public void GetUI()
{
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        if (child.tag == "UI Canvas")
        {
            currentUI = child.GetComponent<UI>();
        } 
    }
 }
```

Where I may have a different active "UI" depending on the scene. It might be the main game scene, or the menu scene. Now, I can just interact with the UI manager via generic/abstract methods like LoadUI() or HideUI().

Tbf, this really should be handled by events but it's overkill for my current project.